# Copy working directory from one terminator screen to another

Tags: terminator

How can one copy with keyboard shortcuts the working directory of one terminator screen to another ?

For example, I have two split windows (thanks to Ctrl+Shift+E). One of them has its working directory (wd) set to `~` and the other has its wd set to `~/work/old/project/foo/bidule/version-2.6.7-a-beta/empty/test/latest`. I would like to change the wd of the first to wd of the second.

First method, type `cd ~/work/old/…` on the first split window. This works, but its a difficult task because the directory name is long and hard to type.

Second method, type `cd` on the first split window, then copy and paste the path from the prompt of the second terminal (or from `pwd` if the prompt does not contain the complete path). This works, but we need to copy and paste a text from a terminal with the mouse, which is a difficult task for someone who has always his hands on the keyboard. :)

Is there a way with shortcuts to do the same stuff ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm running BASH on Debian Jessie derived Bunsen Linux; terminator 0.97)

My default terminator defines Ctrl+Tab as 'Focus the next terminal' and
seems to switch the cursor back and forth between split terminals.

You might have to also install xdotool:

> $ sudo apt-get install xdotool

Then use the X selection to save the current working directory & paste it over to the other terminal.

> echo $PWD | xsel -i; xdotool key Ctrl+Tab; xdotool type 'cd $(xsel
>   -o)'; xdotool key Return

Comment: Same solution as mine (`xsel` & `xclip` do almost the same thing), except that yours automatically switches the terminal.

Comment: Note that this does not work with wayland ([http://superuser.com/questions/1032270/wayland-alternative-for-xorgs-xdotool])

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method that is based on a copy/paste, but that is available on keyboard.

Record two aliases in your `.bashrc` (or into your shell configuration file, I do not know zsh, csh…):

```
alias cywd='pwd | xclip -i' # CopY WD
alias pswd='cd "xclip -o"'  # PaSte WD
```

Then, you are able to copy the current working from a terminal by typing `cywd` and go to this folder by typing `pswd` into another terminal.

This solution is not perfect, mainly because is not easily available if a program is launched on the terminal you want to copy the WD from (for example `vim` or `emacs -nw`). However, it works. Waiting for better…